# Joining a large stream of futures

Tags: rust

I have code like the following:

```
let group_futures = users
    .chunks(settings.users_per_group)
    .map(|chunk| { create_group(&mut client.clone(), chunk) });
```

Now this `create_group()` is an async function that does a call to a backend and returns a future. The function never fails in the sense that it retries and bunch of times and panics if it fails (it's a setup of a load tester, so errors at this point just require rerunning it).

Is there a simple efficient way to join on all the futures and returning a Vec with their values?

Comment: hint: [`FuturesUnordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html)